# Windows 7 Connection Sharing unable to access some sites

Tags: windows-7, networking

I have a pretty sad networking situation that involves connecting to an open Wireless network and sharing that connection to an Ethernet that is plugged into a Linksys router. This has been done with XP and Windows 7, and it works great with XP.

The problem with Windows 7 is that only some DNS will work. I don't know if it's been poisoned on the network above us (which we have no control over), but we've tried clearing the DNS cache as well as moving to using Google's DNS servers (8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4). Here is a really quick list of sites that won't respond to DNS requests at all via `dig`, although if I get the IP address I can ping them:

facebook.com
yuilibrary.com
twitter.com

A lot of sites do work though. Anyone have an idea? It may be a subnet problem? If anyone wants more info let me know.

Comment: You realize this site is about programming, right? I don't see this as a programming-related question. You may want to contact your ISP and/or hardware manufacturer(s) for tech support.

Comment: Run your own DNS server on your box, and point your network connection at it?

Answer (score 0):

Not really a lot of information about your network, however, it sounds to me like it is being blocked either at the router or ISP level.

First, see if you can bypass the block by using a secure connection - for example, instead of http://www.facebook.com try https://www.facebook.com

Assuming it is being blocked at your ISP, I recommend you try using a proxy server such as [Proxify](http://www.proxify.com) or [Hidemyass](http://www.hidemyass.com), alternatively you can try using [TOR](http://www.torproject.org/).

If it is not being blocked by your ISP, I really need to know more about your current network to help you further.

Comment: how could these sites be blocked "either at the router or ISP level" when they are accessible with Windows XP but not with Windows 7?